Dropdown menu is losing all styling when .active class is enabled but with on:hover it works
I encountered a strange behavior in a dropdown component and I can not figure out what causes the problem. Any help is really appreciated!
It is a simple dropdown. I used React, CSS and JavaScript without any extensions. Everything works as expected "on:hover". For that I set the CSS-styling of the dropdown content to "display: block".
For mobile and touch-devices I now also have to include the possibility to open the menu on-click and close it again when a choice is selected, or the user clicks outside the menue. The last two functionalities work fine.
But when I do the same with the ".active" some stylings are lost, and the dropdown does not expand to the bottom anymore but inside-out vertically.
What did I wrong?
Here is the code from the component:
import React, { useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

import './SortResults.css'

const SortResults = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    let menuRef = useRef();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let handler = (e)=>{
          if(!menuRef.current.contains(e.target)){
            setIsOpen(false);
            console.log(menuRef.current);
          }      
        };
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);

        return() =>{
          document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
        }
    });

    function handleClick(key) {
            setIsOpen(false);
    }

    return (   
            <div className={"dropdown"}>
                    <div className={'select'} onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
                        <p className={'selectChoice'}>
                            {selectedOption != '' ? selectedOption : 'sort by'}
                        </p>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className="arrow" icon={faChevronDown} />
                    </div>
                    <div className={isOpen ? "dropdownContent.active" : "dropdownContent"
                         ref={menuRef}>
                         {sortOptions.map((option,index) => 
                             (<div 
                                 className={index === 0 ? 'sortChoice1' : 'sortChoice'}
                                 key={index} 
                                 value={option} 
                                 onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
                                     {option}
                              </div>))
                          }
                    </div> 
              </div>
            );

};

export default SortResults;

And the CSS-Styling:
.dropdown, .dropdown.active {
    z-index: 10; 
    position: relative;
    width: 15em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    outline: 2.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 1em;
    background-color: var(--blue);
    cursor: pointer;

    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-optical-sizing: auto;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variation-settings:"slnt" 0;
}

.select {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 100%;
}

.selectChoice {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-optical-sizing: auto;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variation-settings:"slnt" 0;
}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
}

.dropdownContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 2.5em;
    outline: 2.5px solid black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    background-color: var(--blue);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sortChoice1, .sortChoice {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-block: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 0;
    transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

 .sortChoice{
    border-top: 2.5px solid black;
} 

.dropdown:hover .dropdownContent {
    display: block;
}

.dropdownContent.active {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.sortChoice:hover, .sortChoice1:hover {
    background-color: var(--lightbeige);
}

.dropdown:hover:hover .arrow {
    transform: rotate(180deg)
}

This part of the code behaves also strange:
.dropdown:hover {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

On hover it has influence at the bottom of the <div> with the className="select". Active it is influencing the bottom of the whole container.
I tried : restructuring, adding to everything ".active" classes with the initial styling and including the corresponing conditional styling in the component-file ...and some more. But I assume that i might made a really simple mistake in the structure?
When i try to add the active class to the <div> with the className="dropdown" like so:
.dropdown.active .dropdownContent {
    display: block;
}

and include the conditional styling in the component, allmost all stylings get lost.

I know that the dependency array was missing in the useEffect(). I fixed that. but it did not cause the problem.

className={isOpen ? "dropdownContent.active" : "dropdownContent" - if you want to give an element multiple classes, then they need to be separated by whitespace, not concatenated with a dot.

Hey CBroe, that helped! I messed up with using the .active class...well lack of knowledge...but I might get there sometime. Thank you.

I don't know if this is the problem but there is a small error. You are missing the useState import.
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"; // missing useState

You are missing a closing brace (}).
{/*  // missing "}" in div */}
  <div
    className={isOpen ? "dropdownContent.active" : "dropdownContent"}
    ref={menuRef}
  >

can you try something like that?
               {isOpen && <div>
                     {sortOptions.map((option,index) => 
                         (<div 
                             className={index === 0 ? 'sortChoice1' : 'sortChoice'}
                             key={index} 
                             value={option} 
                             onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
                                 {option}
                          </div>))
                      }
                </div> }


Please see [answer] and take the [tour]. Social discussion is not appropriate in an answer.

Dear bensghost, thank you very much for your answer. I copied the code and deletet a lot of imports and other functionalities, like updating the data-state etc which have nothing to do with the styling of the dropdown-component. I wanted to reduce the code on the minimum that causes the problem. By that I accidently have deleted the useState() and the closing brace.

But it in the end this is not what is causing the problem. Both (useState and the bracket) are there in the code that does not work. Thank you for reading my code so carefully!
